# What do I need for viewing and playing Flash games on my PC?

Tags: windows-xp, download, flash

What do I need for viewing and playing Flash games on my Windows XP PC?

If I need to download something, can I get a link?

Answer (score 1):

Download Flash player from http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer

Comment: Just a side note, if you are insane with the number of installed browsers like me, you need to follow that link in different browsers to make sure you have what you need for each browser.  I run FF, Chrome (comes with flash builtin), IE, Opera and others for browser testing.

Comment: Ah, good point.

Comment: Actually, you only need to do it twice - once for IE, and once for everything else. IE is just "special" like that.

Comment: thanks for the help, from where i can download flashplayer as a file that i can install on computer without internet ?